# How Can I Enable a a disabled button by right-click on it in C# forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, isenabled

In my mini app in C# I have a button that I want to enable and disable it by right click on it. i.e. when button is enabled by right click it turn to disable and when it is disable, right click on it change it's status to enable. Disabling of enabled button is easy and straightforward but enabling it by right click on it, is not possible; because the button is disabled and not event is sent to emaciate code.
How Can I do?

Answer (score 4):

The mouse events of a disabled control are passed down to its `Parent`.

You can catch them there and test if the cursor is on the button.

Example:

```
if (button1.Bounds.Contains(e.Location)) button1.Enabled = true;
```

If you have several buttons you need to test them all..:

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (ctl is Button && ctl.Bounds.Contains(e.Location)) 
            ctl.Enabled = true;
    } 
}
```

If only the right mouse button is supposed to enable, add a test for it, maybe like so:

```
if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Right) && 
    ctl is Button && ctl.Bounds.Contains(e.Location))
```

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..

Answer (score 0):

Right-clicking to enable and disable a button is not standard or recommended button behavior, so the API completely leaves out an easy implementation for it. Once the button is disabled, it no longer captures mouse events, but the form does.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Boolean _button1IsRightClicked;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _button1IsRightClicked = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hi");
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.X >= button1.Location.X && e.X <= (button1.Location.X + button1.Width) &&
            e.Y >= button1.Location.Y && e.Y <= (button1.Location.Y + button1.Height))
        {
            _button1IsRightClicked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _button1IsRightClicked = false;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.X >= button1.Location.X && e.X <= (button1.Location.X + button1.Width) &&
            e.Y >= button1.Location.Y && e.Y <= (button1.Location.Y + button1.Height))
        {
            _button1IsRightClicked = false;
            enableDisableButton1(button1.Enabled);
        }
        else
        {
            _button1IsRightClicked = false;
        }
    }

    private void enableDisableButton1(Boolean isEnabled)
    {
        if (isEnabled)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            isEnabled = false;
        }else
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            isEnabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            _button1IsRightClicked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _button1IsRightClicked = false;
        }
    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && _button1IsRightClicked == true)
        {
            _button1IsRightClicked = false;
            enableDisableButton1(button1.Enabled);
        }
        else
        {
            _button1IsRightClicked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it add any value to the other answer?